# Passing array from a form to another

Tags: forms

I have a custom module that has a form like this :

```
    /*
 * Sytems settings form for listing skill
 */
function skillbar_form($form, &$form_state) {

    $form['skill1'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('What's your skill ?'),
        '#default_value' => variable_get('skill1'),
        '#description' => t('Enter your skill'),
    );
    $form['skill2'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('What's your second skill'),
        '#default_value' => variable_get('skill2'),
        '#description' => t('Enter your second skill'),
    );


    return(system_settings_form($form));

}
```

This form will get information from user like (`What's your skill ?`).

**FIRST :** i want to redirect user after submiting this form to another form
**SECOND** : i want to reuse data from first form ("`what's yous skill ?`") and use variable's from first form to creat second form an let user to add their percentage of skill like : `90 %`
Any help would be appreciate it

**EDIT :**
[image]

Comment: Looks like you are looking for a multi step form solution, have a look here for references http://growingventuresolutions.com/blog/drupal-7-multistep-forms-using-variable-functions.html

Comment: did you mean creating multistep form.. 

check out this http://growingventuresolutions.com/blog/drupal-7-multistep-forms-using-variable-functions.html

Comment: Thank you guys . i've try it and kind of got idea from this but is it possible to show all the information in a table or somthing else after submiting all the form ?

Comment: and let me say that : i want to have two steps . first what's your skill and second what's your percentage of your skill !!!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use 'rebuild' property of forms here (used in multi-steps form) :

```
 function skillbar_form($form, &$form_state) {
   if (!empty($form_state['storage']['myvalue'])) {
    drupal_set_message(t("You submitted: @name", array('@name' => $form_state['storage']['myvalue'])));
   }
   $form['skill1'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t("What's your skill ?"),
    '#default_value' => variable_get('skill1'),
    '#description' => t("Enter your skill"),
   );
   $form['skill2'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t("What's your second skill"),
    '#default_value' => variable_get('skill2'),
    '#description' => t('Enter your second skill'),
   );
   $form['submit_button'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Save'),
   );
   return $form;
  }

 function skillbar_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
  $form_state['storage']['myvalue'] = $form_state['values']['skill1'];
  $form_state['redirect'] = ANY_URL;
 }
```

Comment: thx for your answer , ok and after that how to connect them to another form ?

Comment: In the submit handler: 
$form_state['redirect'] = 'url';

Comment: thx , but i didnt understand it . it's my fault

Comment: I am editing above code for you. Replace 'url' above accordingly.

Comment: ok thx a million and do i need to add another item to hook menu () ?

Comment: Why you need another menu item ?

Comment: when i submit this form i get the message and said : You submitted:"something" in first textfield . 
because second form is in another url